# ListView automatically moving to top when I scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, timer, android-asynctask

I am working on `TCP socket` and `ListView` which has 20 list items. 
From server I receive some set of data for every 5 sec, which I need to display in `listview`.

My Problem is.

When I scroll my List and I receive a 2nd set of data from server which I need to update my list items, then my `listview` automatically moving to top. I need to stop it.

My code which is updating my List view. This code is in onPostExecute of AsyncTask.

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> result) {
    adb = new ArrayAdapter<User>(DefaultMarketWatch.this, R.layout.rssitemview, result) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            try {
                if (null == view) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) DefaultMarketWatch.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
                }
                final User u = list.get(position);
                if (null != u) {
                    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                    TextView ltp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ltp);
                    TextView high = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.high);
                    TextView low = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.low);
                    TextView persendBold = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.persent_bold);

                    persendBold.setText(u.getAskPrice());
                    ltp.setText(u.getLtp());
                    title.setText(u.getSymbol());
                    high.setText(u.getHigh());
                    low.setText(u.getLow());
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return view;
        }

    };

    if (adb != null) {
        lv.setAdapter(adb);
        adb.notifyDataSetChanged();
        int currentPos = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        lv.setSelection(currentPos);
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: post code how you are updating listview..

Comment: This happens because every 5 sec, you update the list.. which resets the scroll position. Post your code, so we can help you with a solution..

Comment: Are you using setSelection in your code?

Comment: I have updated my code. Please have look. I used setSelection() did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

The question is: What behavior do you prefer? If the List Items change completely, it is reasonable to show the first Element. However, if you just want the same position as before with the new data, you could do something like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> result) {
    int currentPos = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    adb = new ArrayAdapter<User>(DefaultMarketWatch.this, R.layout.rssitemview, result) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            try {
                if (null == view) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) DefaultMarketWatch.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
                }
                final User u = list.get(position);
                if (null != u) {
                    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                    TextView ltp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ltp);
                    TextView high = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.high);
                    TextView low = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.low);
                    TextView persendBold = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.persent_bold);

                    persendBold.setText(u.getAskPrice());
                    ltp.setText(u.getLtp());
                    title.setText(u.getSymbol());
                    high.setText(u.getHigh());
                    low.setText(u.getLow());
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return view;
        }

    };

     //previous null check completely unnessesary, because you initialized it just before
    lv.setAdapter(adb);
    adb.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lv.setSelection(currentPos);

    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: Please see my code I have updated it. I used setSelection() but did not worked.

Comment: @user2085965 You call the `lv.getFirstVisibleItem()`too late (after you set a new Adapter to it). Try my updated Code, it should work, if lv is initialized (can't see where in your code `lv` comes from)

Comment: @user2085965 "did not work" is not a good response. 1. What hasn't worked. 2. What did you expect? 3. What happens instead? 4. Are there Errors? 5. Have you verified you data? 6. Have you logged, what comes out from `lv.getFirstVisibleItem()` (if so, please post, if not, do it)! do not expect that SO members completely SOLVE your problems. We could only try to help based on given informations. Its on YOU to provide them to us as detailed as possible. Just a reminder for future questions: The more information you provide, the more likely it is that someone could help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you set a new `adapter` everytime for your `listView`. My solution is to implement a custom array adapter which supports `update` list at runtime..

Step 1) define a custom `ArrayAdapter` as follows:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>
{
    ArrayList<User> list;

    public MyArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<User> result) {
       super (context, textViewResourceId, objects);
       this.list = result;
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<User> updatedList) {
        this.list = updatedList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        try {
            if (null == view) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) DefaultMarketWatch.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
            }
            final User u = list.get(position);
            if (null != u) {
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                TextView ltp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ltp);
                TextView high = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.high);
                TextView low = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.low);
                TextView persendBold = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.persent_bold);

                persendBold.setText(u.getAskPrice());
                ltp.setText(u.getLtp());
                title.setText(u.getSymbol());
                high.setText(u.getHigh());
                low.setText(u.getLow());
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Initialize `adb` as follows (in the `onCreate` or where ever before starting the `AsyncTask`:

```
adb = new MyArrayAdapter(DefaultMarketWatch.this, R.layout.rssitemview, new ArrayList<User>());
lv.setAdapter(adb);
adb.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Your post execute will NOW just tell the adapter that list is updated, and call notify data set changed.

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<User> result) {
    adb.updateList(result);
    adb.notifyDataSetChanged();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```